# separate stdout and stderr of system() command

Tags: external-command

I can catch the output of running a system command via `system()` or `systemlist()`, but that actually gives me the result of stdout and stderr combined. 
As I am only interested in stdout (and may use stderr for other purposes), this isn't useful for me.

How can I separate the output of a system command between stdout and stderr?

Comment: You're mixing up the in / out / err names quite a bit (but I think I understand what you mean). Please do some proofreading and correct the references to _stdin_.

Comment: @IngoKarkat Sorry, you are right, of course. I have fixed the question.

Comment: use `job_start`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Vim's `system()` indeed captures both standard out and standard error by default. If you just want one of those, just use the normal shell means to redirect the other to the *null device*.

For example, ignore stderr (`2>`) with Bash:

```
:echo system('grep root /etc/passwd /doesnotexist 2>/dev/null')
```

On Windows, you'd use `2>NUL` instead.

Alternatively, you could (temporarily) modify the [`'shellredir'`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27shellredir%27) setting; e.g. by dropping the `2>&1` from it to ignore stderr. (*Thanks @ChristianBrabandt for the tip!*)

#### separate stdout and stderr

If you need both (but separately), that's a bit tricky. You could:

- redirect one / both into a temp file and read that via [`readfile()`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#readfile%28%29), or via another `system('cat /tmpfile')`
- invoke the command twice, ignoring first stdout and then stderr
- add prefixes (via `sed`) to one / both (possible with fancy piping and redirections), read all in one fell swoop, and separate inside Vim

Comment: Urgh, that's ugly. Being dependend on the operating system _and_ additionally on the shell doesn't sound nice. The alternatives to separate stdout/stderr for using both also isn't funny, but I think your first approach for is doable without too much effort and still usable. What I dislike even more is the system dependency… As this seems to be the only way to achieve this, I accept your answer. Thank you very much!

Comment: No, it only caputes stderr, if the shellredir option contains `2>%1` and this depends on the `shell` option. So simply setting `:set srr=>` should *fix*  capturing the error

Comment: Well, external commands naturally depend on the environment. In practice, most Unix/Linux shells are very similar (unless you're using an exotic one), and if you use Cygwin or WSL on Windows, you could even get away with a single implementation.

Answer (score 2):

The separation can be done using jobs.

```
vim9script

job_start('grep root /etc/passwd /doesnotexist', {
  out_cb: On_stdout,
  err_cb: On_stderr,
})

def On_stdout(ch: channel, msg: string)
  # do something with msg
enddef

def On_stderr(ch: channel, msg: string)
  # do something with msg
enddef
```

Comment: Thank you for the example. But there is no need to use vim9script for it. Regular vimscript would do as well and would be way more compatible.

Comment: In my opinion, it is not a bad thing to start using vim9 script more often given its many improvements over legacy vimscript.

Answer (score 0):

```
:h r! -- [range]r[ead] !{cmd}
```

looks like a possible alternative to system() to
insert its standard output below
the cursor or the specified line.

It says
`shellredir` is used to save
the output of the command, which can be set to include
stderr or not
as @IngoKarat mentioned.

`:help set-default` to put it back.

A similar question and answer: [read from external command captures stderr as well](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/11731/43320).